# CString Format problem and differences in Windows XP and 7?

Tags: c++, sqlite, mfc, formatting, cstring

There is a problem, below code works for Windows 7 and not for Windows XP? By any chance, do you know the reason for that? Thanks in advance. I have checked that it is not a DB error.

For Win 7 it returns what is stored, also the same case for Win XP. But, Formatting in XP sets CString as **`""`**.

```
if(getDB()->getEncoding() == IDatabase::UTF8){
    a_value.Format(_T("%s"), sqlite3_column_text(getCommand()->getStatement(), idx));
}else{
    a_value.Format(_T("%s"), sqlite3_column_text16(getCommand()->getStatement(), idx));
}
```

Also, we are sure that it is not a unicode issue.

Comment: The database is probably UTF-8, and you are building using Windows "Unicode", which is UTF-16 , use `a_value.Format(L"%s", sqlite3_column_text16(getCommand()->getStatement(), idx))` for both cases.

Comment: You are right, but we have an encoder to solve this problem also.

Answer (score 0):

This really doesn't appear to be a Windows issue. Are you sure you're not doing different builds between the version that works and the one that doesn't?

The code above is problematic because if you do a Unicode build, `sqlite3_column_text()` will return the wrong type of string. For Unicode builds, you'd want `sqlite3_column_text16()` instead.

Comment: Edited according to your feedback. and I am sure that it is not a Unicode issue. Also, Version and build are correct. Thanks, though.

Comment: @baris_a: Your edit does not solve the problem. You need to know if you are compiling your code for Unicode or multibyte. This is unrelated to the encoding in your database.

Comment: It is build for Unicode. It is not a Unicode issue also. We have an Encoder to convert if it is required. It is in Win XP. Formatting results an empty CString.

Comment: @baris_a: Then please see my original answer. It still applies. You need `sqlite3_column_text16()`. Your edit does not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

check if character set configured during compilation is the same on the two platform

unicode

or

multibyte

maybe it helps, bye